# ipaddress module and IPv6 reverse pointer

Tags: python, dns, ipv6

i'll try to explain my problem with examples:
when i'm using ipv6calc to build a reverse domain this is what i want to get:

```
$ ipv6calc --out revnibbles.arpa 2001:0db8:85a3::/48
No input type specified, try autodetection...found type: ipv6addr
3.a.5.8.8.b.d.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa.
.
```

heres an example w/o given prefix (128 default) to see the difference

```
$  ipv6calc --out revnibbles.arpa 2001:0db8:85a3::
No input type specified, try autodetection...found type: ipv6addr
0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.3.a.5.8.8.b.d.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa.
```

now im trying to build the reverse domain in python with the ipaddress module and with a given prefix like above (important)

```
import ipaddress
print(ipaddress.IPv6Network(u"2001:0db8:85a3::/48").reverse_pointer)
```

output is

```
8.4./.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.3.a.5.8.8.b.d.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa
```

Seems like the module did not consider that.
I have also tried the module IPy, but its buggy as hell and not usable in my opinion. Does anyone have an idea how to solve that? i would prefer one without the usage of shell commands (ipv6calc).

Thank you in advance

Comment: I disagree with the close vote. This question already contains a MCVE which clearly demonstrates the problem, and how it differs from the desired result. My Python is not quite strong enough to solve it though.

Answer (score 2):

The `reverse_pointer` is implemented that way:

```
    def _reverse_pointer(self):
        """Return the reverse DNS pointer name for the IPv6 address.
        This implements the method described in RFC3596 2.5.
        """
        reverse_chars = self.exploded[::-1].replace(':', '')
        return '.'.join(reverse_chars) + '.ip6.arpa'
```

So it clearly will not take into account the prefix. Note that it specifically speaks about IPv6 **address**, not network/prefix.

First you will have a better answer by doing:

```
print(ipaddress.IPv6Network(u"2001:0db8:85a3::/48").network_address.reverse_pointer)
```

which gives: `0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.3.a.5.8.8.b.d.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa` which is proper version, even if not what you want.

You either need to subclass `IPv6Network` and rewrite `_reverse_pointer` to your liking or muck directly with its current result as the following, that could work but has edge cases:

```
print(ipaddress.IPv6Network(u"2001:0db8:85a3::/48").network_address.reverse_pointer[(2*(128-48)/4):])
3.a.5.8.8.b.d.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa
```

because the full result is 32 nibbles (hexadecimal digit) separated by a dot (besides the final `.ip6.arpa`), and `128-48` is the number of bits for the non prefix part, and since the previous is in bits, you need to count bytes in hexadecimal so `/4` but `*2` because each nibble is present with a following dot.

Comment: i had a simlar solution ```network = ipaddress.IPv6Network('2001:db8:85a3::/48', False); '.'.join(network.network_address.reverse_pointer.split('.')[32-(network.prefixlen//4):])``` which is still not satisfying. if you compare  the output with ipv6calc and some special prefixes (49 for example) neither yours nor mine works right